# R: Trying to determine which decile each data point is in, for all variables in a data frame

Tags: r, apply, quantile

I have some data containing information on the prices consumers are willing to pay for certain services. I'm trying to find the deciles each response falls into, for several services by using the cut function.

```
for (i in 2:13){
    x<-quantile(data1[,i],c(0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1),na.rm=TRUE)

    data1[paste(names(data1[i]), "deciles", sep="_")] <- cut(data1[,i], breaks=x, includ)
}
```

However, I have two problems: there are some variables for which two deciles are the same value (e.g. 0 =0, .1=0), which the cut function will not accept. Also, for the initial columns where the code does work, I get the actual decile and not the decile number (for example "(1.99,2.56]" instead of .2.

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem: you can only use the `unique` breaks and pass those to `cut`.  For the second, convert the factor to an integer and use the integer as the index in the `probs` vector to pull out the appropriate quantile break.

```
## Some sample data, the third column will fail for `cut`
set.seed(0)
data1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=sample(0:5, 100, rep=T))
qs <- seq(0, 1, by=0.1)                                                      # probs for quantile
for (i in 1:3){
    x <- quantile(data1[,i], qs, na.rm=TRUE)
    used <- qs[which(diff(c(0, x)) > 0)]                                     # which quantiles worked
    cuts <- cut(data1[,i], breaks=unique(x), include=T)                      # factors as you had them
    data1[paste(names(data1[i]), "deciles", sep="_")] <- cuts
    data1[paste(names(data1[i]), "num", sep="_")] <- used[as.integer(cuts)]  # numeric values
}
#            x          y z       x_deciles x_num       y_deciles y_num z_deciles
# 1  1.2629543  0.7818592 0     (1.24,2.44]   1.0      (0.78,1.5]   0.9   [0,1.7]
# 2 -0.3262334 -0.7767766 3 (-0.421,-0.252]   0.4 (-0.956,-0.714]   0.3     (2,3]
# 3  1.3297993 -0.6159899 1     (1.24,2.44]   1.0 (-0.714,-0.459]   0.4   [0,1.7]
# 4  1.2724293  0.0465803 5     (1.24,2.44]   1.0  (0.0262,0.376]   0.7     (4,5]
# 5  0.4146414 -1.1303858 5   (0.234,0.421]   0.7   [-1.68,-1.12]   0.1     (4,5]
# 6 -1.5399500  0.5767188 5   [-2.22,-1.07]   0.1    (0.376,0.78]   0.8     (4,5]
#   z_num
# 1   0.3
# 2   0.6
# 3   0.3
# 4   0.8
# 5   0.8
# 6   0.8
```